# How to create Nodejs APi with file inclusion and write feature with REACT for ONLINE SHOPPING STORE creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, rest

I have the follwoing folder sturcture
parent_directory
-client_side
-server_side

I want to write a code in server side as a Rest API so that whenever the api is called with a get request taking parameter username , a React component is created in client_side folder and React-route-dom is also created for routing to that file
so now i have something like this -> [www.mainwebsite.com/username1](http://www.mainwebsite.com/username1)
then after some other request -> [www.mainwebsite.com/username2](http://www.mainwebsite.com/username2)

How can i achieve this ? pls help!

Also in every webpage of each user , there will be the user's online SHOP for selling goods

PLS HELP

Comment: If u have got other ways to achieve this pls share

Comment: Problem is how can i show stores of people